# squid config setting. round-robin interval

Tags: squid

Which tag or parameter can be used in squid.conf configuration to address each neighboring peer, not with every request, but after some time or quantitative interval.

Now with every request it goes to a new peer, but I need the peer to change every few minutes or every 10 requests.

```
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0
http_access allow all
http_port 3128
server_persistent_connections off
cache_peer 45.72.51.207     parent  7775 7 proxy-only round-robin default login=login
cache_peer 23.229.126.58    parent  7587 7 proxy-only round-robin default login=login
cache_peer 23.229.126.136   parent  7665 7 proxy-only round-robin default login=login
cache_peer 45.72.55.94      parent  7131 7 proxy-only round-robin default login=login
cache_peer 45.72.55.30      parent  7067 7 proxy-only round-robin default login=login   

never_direct allow all
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood with your explanation;
You need **Weighted Round Robin**.

It operates like a circle selecting the first peer, then the second, then the third, etc until
all peers have been used then selects the first again and repeats the sequence.

You could set **weight=** at the end of peer config line

```
Modified with weight= option to un-balance the connections.
Un-balance the connections to pick this peer N times each cycle.
```

Also you could set **max-conn** at the end of peer config line for maximum connection to peers.

sample for *maximum connection* :

```
cache_peer Server01 parent 80 0 no-query originserver login=PASS max-conn=10
cache_peer Server02 parent 80 0 no-query originserver login=PASS max-conn=50
cache_peer Server03 parent 80 0 no-query originserver login=PASS max-conn=60
```

sample for *weight* :

```
cache_peer Server01 parent 80 0 no-query originserver login=PASS weight=5
cache_peer Server02 parent 80 0 no-query originserver login=PASS weight=10
cache_peer Server03 parent 80 0 no-query originserver login=PASS weight=20
```